# Arrange items at the top of a ScalingLazyColumn

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, wear-os, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

My layout contains a single `ScrollingLazyColumn` that fills the entire screen.
The first item should be at the top of the screen, but it is centered.

**Here is my code:**

```kotlin
@Preview(device = Devices.WEAR_OS_SMALL_ROUND, showBackground = true, backgroundColor = 0xff000000)
@Composable
private fun PreviewTest() {
    Scaffold() {
        ScalingLazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
        ) {
            item {
                Text("this should be at the top")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've already used`verticalArrangement`, but it does absolutely nothing (`Bottom` doesn't work either).

The same code will work perfectly fine if I switch out `ScalingLazyColumn` for a regular `LazyColumn`.

Is there a bug in the code?

**EDIT:**
I just realized that `ScalingLazyColumn` is marked with `@OptIn(ExperimentalWearFoundationApi::class)`...

Can I file a bug report somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to use this to prevent moving down elements automatically:

```kotlin
autoCentering = AutoCenteringParams(
  itemIndex = 2
)
```